# Deleting data files in java

Tags: java, linux, operating-system

In my knowledge when you delete a file the pointer of the file just get removed but the data of the file is still there ready to get overwrite and in Linux there is **Shred** that overwrite the file for 3 times by default

My question is how to write a code that does the same as shred but I don't know any keywords to use in my search and I never found source code of shred or any thing like it

Comment: Open the file, overwrite it, close it, and delete it.

Comment: It is that easy ? As i searched there are different algorithms to delete files ... if it is that easy then what the algorithm does ? for example : DoD 5220.22-M

Comment: You already know that Linux and Linux utilities like Shred are open source, yes? That means that the code is freely available on the web. What if you did a search? Maybe you'd find stuff like [this](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/shred.c), which would answer all of your questions. Avoid posting to Stack Overflow until you've properly researched first. It's poor form to ask people to do things for you that you can do yourself.

Comment: The need for cryptographic overwrite is nonsense, with the possible exception of your adversary having millions of dollars to spend recovering your data.  A disk that returns something other than "the exact data last written" is technically described as "broken".

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to overwrite the file three times, with random data, then it's easy enough to repeat "open; overwrite; close" three times.

Comment: Source for shred - https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/shred.c

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry for not being able to find the source code of shred